# Android: On Item Click Listener for List View Base Adapter implementation

Tags: java, android

Can someone point give me an example of a On item click listener used for a list view with base adapter?

My list view contains two text views and a check box. I want to create an on item click listener so that when a item (or row) is pressed, it ticks the corresponding row check box.

I tried to Google it but could not find any examples of it

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the adapter does not really matter, but i believe what you are trying to do is pretty simple, first you need to get a refrence to your `ListView` which i will refer to as `listView`

after setting your adapter you can use `setOnItemClickListener` to create the click action,

```
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //here you can use the position to determine what checkbox to check
            //this assumes that you have an array of your checkboxes as well. called checkbox
            checkBox[position].setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented this and got a toast to display stating the item position. Could you explain this array of checkboxes? The problem I am having now is transferring a clicked item to check the row's checkbox

Comment: sure, i have been away from my computer for a few hours but hopefully this is still helpful, Whenever you instantiate your checkboxes, if its in code, keep a reference to them in an array, if its in XML you will have to do `findViewById` for each one. If yo uneed more info i can check back in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple, after you perform the action "setAdapter" You have to do this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You click on position:"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Also how to toast corresponding a column value ?, Here is a only toast position, then how to toast that positioned column valu

Answer (score 0):

The following code works correctly:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                          View view, int position, long id) { 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   "You click on position:"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

But when I clicked `items` then it goes to other activities. What should I do?

Comment: I don't think this is an answer, but am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the elements of your listview row using View parameter of OnItemClick() method.  e.g.

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                      View view, int position, long id) { 
    // second parameter View view entire row object that is clicked  - in your case 
    // two text views and the checkbox
    // supposing your checkbox is set up with an id in the xml as idchkbox
    // You can access it by findview by id and set it true or false;
        android.widget.CheckBox  chkbox = view.findViewbyId(R.id.idchkbox);
        chkbox.setChecked = true;
        return;
    });
```

Comment: Please also try to  explain your solution